# Why are CSRF Tokens not required on these REST Web Services endpoints?

Tags: 10

I am using the `miniOrange API Authentication` module to handle API Key Authorization for my custom Rest Endpoints built by extending the `REST Web Services` module.

I notice that my POST and PATCH methods work perfectly fine without a CSRF token provided by the `/session/token` endpoint. Does API Key Authorization remove the need for CSRF tokens or why am I able to make successful POST/PATCH requests without a CSRF Token? I thought they were required...

```
/**
 * Provides a My Resource
 * 
 * @RestResource(
 *  id = "my_resource",
 *  label = @Translation("My Resource"),
 *  uri_paths = {
 *    "canonical" = "/my_api/test",
 *    "create" = "/my_api/test"
 *  }
 * )
 */
class MyResource extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * Responds to GET requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function get() {
    $response = ['message' => 'This GET endpoint still needs to be implemented'];
    return new ResourceResponse($response);
  }

  /**
   * Responds to POST requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function post() {
    $response = ['message' => 'This POST endpoint still needs to be implemented'];
    return new ResourceResponse($response);
  }

  /**
   * Responds to PATCH requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function patch() {
    $response = ['message' => 'This PATCH endpoint still needs to be implemented'];
    return new ResourceResponse($response);
  }
```

Comment: What is the path/url that you're posting those PATCH and POST requests?

Comment: it's a custom path for a custom API Resource. In this example, the path is /my_api/test as described in the class signature